# Qt application on touchscreen

Tags: c++, qt, touch, qmainwindow

I made a simple Application using Qt. It has a mainwindow with a button. When the button is clicked a new windows is opened. When I use the mouse to click the button everything works fine. When I try using the touch screen to press the button, the button doesn't always get clicked. Is there anything extra I have to do to make Qt work on touch screens?

Comment: Qt cannot be made to work. If you want a reliable user experience, you cannot use Qt.

Comment: Qt has no good experience with touchscreen. Use QML (QtQuick) !

Comment: Quite a lot of devices run apps with Qt widgets. Overall, missing touch to click translation can be OS problem and then specific Qt framework target. As for QWidget vs. QML I use both and QML also has a load of problems you don't expect.

Comment: Can you provide some more information about what you're running it on? Qt in general can work fine on touchscreens (you can compile for iOS & Android so it needs touchscreen support) but can run into issues with system drivers for other platforms.